# iOS app update not showing on search screen but only on app page only, why?

Tags: ios, mobile

i have released an update of my app on ios store but each time the UPDATE button is not showing on the search list but only on the app page only. any reason why?

for example, on whatsapp it shows on both search and app page. but for my app, it shows OPEN on search and UPDATE on its page. So, users don't know there is an update about it except if they click on the app page itself.

any help will be much appreciated!
thanks!

[whatsapp search image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v37Em.jpg)
[whatsapp app page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDp0m.jpg)

Comment: How long ago did you release the update?  It takes time for  the search index to update.

Comment: after 2-3 days last time it still did not see it...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow this rule with the new version number:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> - MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> - MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
> - PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

Ref.: https://semver.org/

also when you release a new version the store delay 1 to 3 days to spread the new version.

Comment: Semantic versioning is a suggestion and one approach.  It isn't mandatory. The real answer is that it takes time to update the search index after an update

Comment: thanks! will watch and check how long this time it will take, been over 24h so far. the first time, i keep going to search page and seeing open, i thought Apple did not release it but in fact it was and i saw it when i clicked on the app page... really weird!